# Dynamic page. Trouble with getting data

Tags: php, html

I've got  more than 20 links they look like:

```html
<div>
<a href='writer.php?id=1'>1st Writer</a>
<a href='writer.php?id=2'>2nd Writer</a>
<a href='writer.php?id=3'>3d Writer</a>
<a href='writer.php?id=4'>4th Writer</a>
<a href='writer.php?id=5'>5th Writer</a>
</div>
```

How can i get "id" from each href='writer.php?id=' ' and pass it to $id writer.php?

writer.php:

```html
<?$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test.com";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id='$id'";
$result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


if (mysqli_num_rows($result3) > 0) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {

        echo $row[text];
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);?>
```

I just want to click on link and display at new page(writer.php) my data from database where id = that number from href.
But i dont know how to...

Comment: When you print your html such as (<a href='writer.php?id=1'>1st Writer</a>) why do not you print a "id" with the number you need? If you have Stored inside your db all this html it's wrong use, otherwise when you loop for print you can do it

Comment: `$id = (int)$_GET['id']` and do every possible check before injecting the value in a SQL query (e.g. allow a specific range of numbers, deal with unexpected id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

writer.php?id=1

This can be accessed with $_GET['id'] in  your php code

```
  $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

Then write your query based on this id

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id='$id'";
    $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

I would suggest instead of writing procedural way try mysqli in object oriented way

```
   $con = new mysqli("host","user","password","database");
   $id = $con->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
   $result3 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id='$id'");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$id = htmlspecialchars((int)$_GET['id']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id='$id'";
```

http://phpform.net/dynamic.php

Comment: `htmlspecialchars`?! It's a database, not an HTML document.